# "Undefined" added to page content after google Adwords click

Tags: permalinks, html

I have created a 'landing-page' for a wordpress site i've been building. Everything on the page looks great and is formatted properly. The page is now linked to the PPC campaign from google. This is the landing page as seen on the website [Rutberg Breslow landing page](http://rutbergbreslow.com/landing-page/). Although when the extension for google is added on the end it replaces the image with "Undefined" as well as prepending to to the start of the content. As seen here [Same page seen with issue](http://rutbergbreslow.com/landing-page/?gclid=CJy9moeemtMCFR2HswodBYoAHg).

Consider me a novice but i have not seen this issue before with any other landing-pages i have built in the past. If someone could at least explain why this happens i would greatly appreciate.

Comment: That's definitely out of the ordinary. Looking at your source it appears you have 2 separate contact form plugins installed - I wonder if they're conflicting. I would first try disabling all plugins and loading the page in an Incognito window - if it loads fine with the query string then it's one of the plugins. You might also try activating a default theme like 2017 to see if your theme is playing a part. Finally, since the image name and alt text appear to contain special characters, upload a new one that uses just alpha characters in name and alt and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks I will definitely give this a shot, I just thought it was very strange that the tracking parameters on the URL prompted this effect!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a semi-solution for this issue. This is the first time i've ever seen this issue. No other resources have been posted with the same problem, and google was absolutely no assistance.

After disabling all plugins, changing themes and changing text content their was no change. I noticed that the problem only propagated after the /?gclid=xxx parameter was attached which is the auto tracking parameter from google adwords. My temporary solution was to disable the auto-tagging on google adwords which removes the tagging parameter. This returned the site to it's original status.

I'm going to continue my investigation on why auto-tagging caused this issue. But i wanted to post my solution here for anyone that comes across this apparently rare issue.